# How to format dates from server into JS

Tags: angularjs, html, datetime

It might be a super simple solution, but I am struglling with it for a while now.
I am using angular.js and using input time.

The server returns the following date convention:

```
shiftStarted = "2017-01-17 19:55:11"
```

I want to put it as ng-model in the input field:

```
<input type="time" ng-model="shiftStarted" />
```

The problem is that input time should receive a valid JS date format, 
In order to try to solve it I used this solution I found on the web:

- shiftStarted = new Date(shiftStarted.replace(' ', 'T'));

But the following is changing the timezone to UTC.

How can I simply put the date accurately in the input time field without handling tough timezone issues?

Best,
Omri

Comment: *without handling tough timezone issues* Hahahaha, thanks for the good laugh :). There's no way around it when dealing with date/time values.

Answer (score 0):

If your date has been formatted as **YYYY-MM-DD**, the browser will parse it as an [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  (the full format would be **2017-01-17T18:03:26+00:00** at the time of me writing this)

Since no timezone portion was provided (only a date), the browser assumes the timezone is UTC by default.

If you just want to parse a date without bothering with timezones, you could use  [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) (as suggested by Ananth)

Code would be:

```
shiftStarted = moment(shiftStarted, "YYYY-MM-DD").toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the angular-date directive:

`<input type="text" datetime="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ng-model="shiftStarted">`

This also include a parser service. New timezone additions too.

https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime

Answer (score -1):

You could try `date.getTimezoneOffset()`